# Print innerHTML of only div elements with specific class and no id

Tags: javascript, html, class, innerhtml

Question should not have been closed. It's not about grabbing elements
by className.  You need to check that there is no id.  Please reopen.

```
<div class="car">...</div>
<div class="car">...</div>
<div class="car">...</div>
```

Somewhere in my HTML code there are `div` tags with a specific class, like `car`. But they do not have an `id` selector. I am trying to print all of their `innerHTML` in a row but I can't use the code `document.getElementById("car").innerHTML`. How can I achieve this? Thanks

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("car")` will return an array of all divs in DOM with the class name "car"

Comment: @jrend it'll actually return an array of all elements with class "car", which is not necessarily just "div" elements.

Comment: [Did you do any research?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/4665)

Answer (score 1):

Select all the div, with `querySelectorAll()`. This method return an array like object, I convert it to an array with `Array.from()`, in this way I can use `reduce` (method of arrays) method to concatenate all the items of array. Finally I write the string into an output div

```js
const divs = document.querySelectorAll("div.car")
const result = Array.from(divs).reduce((accumulator,currentValue)=> accumulator+=currentValue.innerHTML,'')

document.querySelector('.row-output').textContent = result;
```

```html
<div class="car">First div</div>
<div class="car">Second div</div>
<div class="car">Third div</div>

<div class="row-output"></div>
```

Another way could be this:

```js
    const divs = document.querySelectorAll("div.car")
    const result = Array.from(divs,item => item.innerHTML).join('');
    document.querySelector('.row-output').textContent = result;
```

Comment: Easy to fix:  const divs = `document.querySelectorAll("div.car")`

Answer (score 1):

```js
let cars = document.getElementsByClassName('car')

let html = "";
for (let i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
  if(cars[i].getAttribute('id') == null && cars[i].tagName == "DIV")html += cars[i].innerHTML;
}

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = html
```

```html
<div class="car">1...</div>
<div id='x' class="car">.2.</div>
<p class="car">..3</p>
<div class="car">..4</div>


<div id='output'></div>
```

Comment: op says that div's have a specific class

Comment: see updated answer.  op says div's have no id

Answer (score 0):

You can select with `querySelectorAll` or `getElementsByClassName`

```js
const elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".car"))
console.log(elements.map(el => el.innerHTML).join(''))
```

```html
<div class="car"><span>a</span></div>
<div class="car"><div>b</div></div>
<div class="car"><strong>c</strong></div>
```

Comment: Maybe wouldn't use `getElementsByClassName` as you would have to post process to remove anything that isn't a `div`

Answer (score 0):

You want to query for all the div's with that class. That will return a node list. You then need to iterate over that node list, handling the innerHTML of each once.

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".car");
const outputDiv = document.getElementById("output");
elements.forEach( function (node) {
  outputDiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode(node.innerHTML));
});
```

```html
<div class="car">this </div>
<div class="car">is </div>
<div class="car">a test. </div>

<div id=output></div>
```

Comment: This selects everything that has class "car", not just `div` elements

Comment: That's right. If you want to select only div's w .car then do ("div.car")

Answer (score 0):

The CSS selector you really want is this: `div.car:not([id])`. This will return only `div` elements that have class "car" and do not have `id` set.

```js
console.log(Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('div.car:not([id])'), ({innerHTML}) => innerHTML).join(''))
```

```html
<div class="car">this </div>
<div class="car">is </div>
<div id="two" class="car">not </div>
<div class="car">correct </div>
<span class="car">these </span><br />
<span id="one" class="car">spans</span>
```